# How to force browser to break text where possible?

Tags: html, css

I need to determine minimum width adequate for displaying a possibly wrapped dynamic HTML string. Without word-wrapping this is simple: create a `span`, set its `innerHTML` and read `offsetWidth`. However, I'm not sure how to force linebreaks... Easiest incomplete approach I see is to replace all spaces by `<br/>`, but lines can be wrapped not only on spaces but also e.g. on hyphens.

So, basically, I want a browser to lay out sth. like

```
Max.
word-
wrapped
string
<----->
```

somewhere off-screen to measure width of the longest contained word. Is there a generic way to do that?

**EDIT**

I.e., for no line wraps:

```
function computeWidth (str) {  // code to make it off-screen and caching omitted
    var span = document.createElement ('span');
    document.body.appendChild (span);
    span.innerHTML = str;
    return span.offsetWidth;
}
```

How would I write a similar function which forces line breaks on `str`, presumably playing with `span.style`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `work-break` / `word-wrap` and programmatically inserted soft-hyphens (`&shy;`, but I'd advise you to read up on cross browser problems regarding soft hyphens, as there are quite a few - I normally us the unicode for a soft hypen (U+00AD), but your mileage may vary), and then determine the width with javascript using the range object and measuring cursor offset from the left.

I'm suggesting the use of soft-hyphens, because even the same browser will normally break words differently depending on the OS / which dictionary (on OSX) is used. If that's not an issue for you, you can do it without soft hyphens.

Afaik there is no *generic* way to get what you want in html/js (it's different if you were using something like flash).

Range object: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range

A different approach would be using the canvas object, but you would probably not get exact results there, as there is just too much factors influencing text rendering in browsers nowadays (font, size, kerning, tracking, ...)

Again another approach would be using `<pre>` tags / `whitespace: pre-wrap`, setting the font to what you normally use, and then either emulate breaking words by inserting linebreaks or copying them from still another span/div/whatever set up with word wrap - I haven't tested this yet, but if it works, it might be easer than iterating with the range object.

Edit: Just so it's not only in the comments, still another solution:

Start your container with width 1px, then increase the width, checking the height every time ; when the height decreases, go back one step, and you got your width. Simplest implementation would use 1px increase/1px decrease, but you could of course optimize it to using something like a binary search algorithm, e.g. starting with 1px, then 2px, then 4px increases, then the same backwards, and forwards again and so on till you have a result at a 1px step. But that's only if the 1px inc/dec sollution is too slow ;)

Comment: Hm, copying linebreaks sounds like an interesting idea. In principle, that could be done without `<pre>`, just in a `<span>` with `<br/>`. However, how would I find them given that string is dynamic?

Comment: @user2667759 Now that you ask I'd probably suggest using the Range object again actually - but another thing which comes to mind: You could start offscreen with a huge width, and decrease it, checking the height every time (this could be optimized using binary search algorithm or the like), and as soon as the height increases, you have a new word wrap ; if you only need the minimum width, jus start with 1px width and increase it till the height decreases, then go 1 step back, and you got your width ;)

Comment: Probably too messy to actually bother implementing it, but I like your answer. Besides, you are aparently the only one who bothered to actually understand the question before answering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS `word-break` rule:

> The word-break CSS property is used to specify how (or if) to break lines within words.
>
> **Normal**
>   Use the default line break rule.
>   **break-all**
>    Word breaks may be inserted between any character for non-CJK (Chinese/Japanese/Korean) text.
>   **keep-all**
>   Don't allow word breaks for CJK text.  Non-CJK text behavior is same as normal.

```
<p style="word-break:break-all;">
    Max.word-wrapped string<----->
</p>
```

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break))

Comment: Still breaks are not inserted because width is not constrained. And if I constrain width somehow, value of `offsetWidth` becomes meaningless.

Comment: @user2667759 give that dynamic span `white-space: nowrap` css property.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Add it to the `CSS` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xz4zp/), or read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with the **word-break** Property.

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.